# Java/Eclipse formatter to begin a new line after each function

Tags: java, eclipse

I am stuck with some properties in Eclipse. I would like my formatter (or any formatter) to put a new line after each function. Like:

```
Object myObject = create("this").with("this1")
    .with("this2")
    .with("this3")
    .with("this4");
```

Can someone help me out? Thanks

Comment: Set _Line Wrapping > Wrapping settings > Function Calls > Qualified invocations_ to _Wrap all elements, except first element if not necessary_.

Comment: Thanks. Pretty straight forward and works. I learned something new!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the formatter settings, set ***Line Wrapping > Wrapping settings > Function Calls > Qualified invocations*** to ***Wrap all elements, except first element if not necessary***.